# What are the possible scenarios for JTDS driver to show an "Unspecified Error" message in SQLException?

Tags: sql-server, jakarta-ee, sqlexception, jtds, apache-commons-dbcp

I am working on a production issue which is intermittent, where I only have access to logs.
The application is using [MSSQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1279) & [JTDS 1.3.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.1/)

As per application server logs an exception is thrown when borrowing a connection object from apache commons pool & since only e.getMessage() is logged I see something like

> [DatabaseUtil.getConn()]......**The server returned an unspecified**
>   **error.**

The commons pool is configured to [grow](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW) as required, so possibly there was some error on the DB server when pool was requesting a new connection. But the production DBA team found the DB logs all clear.

What could be the possible error scenarios for JTDS driver to show this type of exception, and DB server to not log it? I am clueless.